# How to align image and text vertically within TD element?

Tags: html, alignment, html-table

```
<td>
<img src="http://blog.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/wp-content/feed-icon-16x16.gif"/>
 My feed
 </td>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]
<sub>(source: [garethjmsaunders.co.uk](http://blog.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/wp-content/feed-icon-16x16.gif))</sub>
 My feed

The icon and the text is misalligned vertically. The icon is on the top of the table cell, the text is on the bottom. Both the text and the icon occupy 16 pixel but the cell still eats up 19. How can I align them to save those 3 pixels?

Comment: Thanx for everyone who helped. I tried all of the solutions except splitting the icon and the text to two TD-s. Only the background image solution worked.

Comment: Here a solution => https://stackoverflow.com/a/57590933/2736742

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, if you choose the background image method, then it is very simple:

```
background: url(feed.png) left center no-repeat
```

Comment: +1, the image should be a background image as it's more decoration than actual content.

Answer (score 9):

The image is aligning to the base line of the text, this does not include the descender height which is the 'tick' in letter like g or y.

If the height of the row/cell is to be fixed, you can add line-height to get it to vertically centre. So for instance, assuming your cell is 16px high:

```
td.feed {
    line-height:16px;
}
```

The other option would be to add the icon as a background image, adding padding-left to the cell:

```
td.feed {
    background: transparent url(/wp-content/feed-icon-16x16.gif) no-repeat left center;
    padding-left: 18px; /* width of feed icon plus 2px spacing */
}
```

The second one would mean you could remove the need for tables at all, now there's an idea...

Comment: I personally use the background image way, the only downside is that the image is not clickable and a lot of users try to click the image before the text.

Comment: If you put the background image on the <a> element it will be clickable.

Comment: Ah. Touche. I had never thought of that. I usually did a span around the a. Interesting.

Answer (score 6):

Other answers that state the image shouldn't be part of the content and is merely for decoration, which is debatable.  I do believe that you should add an empty `alt` attribute to your image so that screen readers can ignore the image if you choose to keep your current method.

The `vertical-align` property is the one you need to be using here, but what you want to use is `text-bottom`.  I'm also going to assume you want this to be a link, so here's a full code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>garethjmsaunders.co.uk</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    a { text-decoration: none; }
    a img { border: 0; vertical-align: text-bottom; }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
  <a href="" title="garethjmsaunders.co.uk rss feed">
    <img alt="" src="http://blog.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/wp-content/feed-icon-16x16.gif" />
    My feed
  </a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If this still isn't desirable, you can experiment with `line-height` and other values for `vertical-align` to see what works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with making it a background image?

```
.feed {
  background: transparent url("http://blog.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/wp-content/feed-icon-16x16.gif") no-repeat scroll left center;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<td>
   <img src="http://blog.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/wp-content/feed-icon-16x16.gif"/>
   <span class="feedTxt">My feed</span>
 </td>

 .feedTxt { line-height: 20px; } /* Or whatever the height of the image is.  Adjust as needed. */
```

Answer (score 1):

simply try "vertical-align: middle" on IMG tag, after than you can also set padding for TD

Answer (score 1):

I tried the background image method but didn't like it as much as this...

In the CSS...

```
.iconLabel {
    position: relative;
    top: -6px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
```

In the page...

```
<td style="text-align:center;">
    <a href="overview.cfm"
        ><img alt="Overview" src="Globe.png" 
        align="middle" border="0" height="60" width="60"
        ><span class="iconLabel">Overview</span
    ></a> 
</td>
```

- Play with the **"top"** attribute to move the text/label up and down.
- Play with the **padding** attribute to change the horizontal space between the icon and the text/label.
- You should check it across any browsers you're concerned about, as they may render with slight differences.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `position: relative; top: 3px;` on the `<img>` tag. You could also try `vertical-align: middle;` on the `<td>` tag, but I don't think it'll work properly, as I'm pretty sure I've encountered this before. You could also put them in separate `<td>` tags, but that's kind of a no-no.

Comment: Why would that be a no-no if you're already using a table? You'll at least get automatic vertical centering...

Comment: Well, I don't know the context in which he has that, there's an off chance the table is still being properly used, however if you were to split it it'd get a little too 2002 for me. That's why I said "kind of" - I'd personally consider it, but there's a lot of CSS purists around these parts.

Comment: i didn't vote it down, somebody else did. I got two vote-downs, lol. People around here are weird sometimes.

Comment: That's probably because someone asking a question about HTML and the two of you probably should be answering. Bit like me answering some Fortran questions having never touched it in 20 years (damn, is it that long?).

Comment: Modifying the HTML alters the semantic meaning of the page. Since this is an issue of layout, not content or semantics, the position should be adjusted with a layout-based solution, either with CSS, or altering the DOM with javascript.

Comment: "The two of you probably shouldn't be answering"? Did you seriously just say that? Wow.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the two elements (image and text) in their own separate table cells. You could nest another table. That's a good place to start. Then you could play around with padding, etc. to adjust.

```
<td>
<table><tr style="vertical-align:top;"><td><img src="path_here" /></td><td>my feed</td></tr></table>
</td>
```

Comment: This sort of nesting of tables decreases the semantic value of the page. Since this is an issue of layout, not content or semantics, the position should be adjusted with a layout-based solution, either with CSS, or altering the DOM with javascript.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a table inside of the td with one row and two tds

```
    <td>
        <table><tr>
            <td><img src="image/myimage.gif" alt="myimage.gif"/></td>
            <td>My text</td>
        </tr></table>
    </td>
```

Comment: i feel this is not the right fix, should be another simple way