# how to vertically align elements in td tag

Tags: html, css

I want to align 3 elements in my `<td>` tag vertically in the center/middle. These are the elements that I want to align:

1. image button (a tag) top arrow image
2. jquery slider
3. image button (a tag) bottom arrow image

Essentially the elements are there for vertically scrolling of a chart. They are a bit misaligned. I want them all to be in center.

My current code is:

```
<td style="vertical-align:top;">                
  <div id="div1" style="display:inline-block; horizontal-align:center; margin-top:5px;">
    <a id="a_top" title="Top" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n" style="border:0px;"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="slider_y" style="height:240px; width:6px; horizontal-align:center; margin-top:10px; "></div>
  <div id="div2" style="display:inline-block;horizontal-align:center;margin-top:10px;">
    <a id="a_bottom" title="Bottom" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-s" style="border:0px;"></a>
  </div>
</td>
```

I am open to removing div tag related to image buttons, but td tag should stay there.

Comment: There is no `horizontal-align` CSS property.

Comment: the two align properties for CSS are `text-align` (for horizontal) and `vertical-align` (for vertical)

Comment: would be useful if you could put up a picture of how you want it

Comment: I found the answer, I will submit it after 8 hours because of restriction on submitting self answers. We just have to add attribute align=center to the main td tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to all for your help. I found the answer myself. This is the new code. Only the td tag has changed to add an additional attribute align=center. This will align all element within td tag in center.

```
<td align="center" style="vertical-align:top;">             
    <div id="div1" style="display:inline-block; horizontal-align:center; margin-top:5px;">
     <a id="a_top" title="Top" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n" style="border:0px;"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="slider_y" style="height:240px; width:6px; horizontal-align:center; margin-top:10px; "></div>
    <div id="div2" style="display:inline-block;horizontal-align:center;margin-top:10px;">
     <a id="a_bottom" title="Bottom" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-s" style="border:0px;"></a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: There is no CSS property `horizontal-align`

Answer (score 32):

Read about vertical-align in table cells [here](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/)

```
vertical-align:middle
vertical-align:top
vertical-align:bottom
```

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Answer (score 21):

**Be careful** when there are **several elements** in the same **`<TD>`**, the **vertical alignment no longer works because the alignment is made on the different elements but together!**

For the **different elements** to be **vertically centered**, they must **be separated** into a new **`<table>`** **with different columns**!

For example, to **align** an **image** with a **`<span>`**:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
<td style="vertical-align:top;">                
  <div id="div1" style="display:inline-block; horizontal-align:center; margin-top:5px;">
    <div align="center"><a id="a_top" title="Top" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n" style="border:0px;"></a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="slider_y" style="height:240px; width:6px; horizontal-align:center; margin-top:10px; "></div>
  <div id="div2" style="display:inline-block;horizontal-align:center;margin-top:10px;">
    <div align="center"><a id="a_bottom" title="Bottom" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-s" style="border:0px;"></a>
      </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

I'm not sure I completely understand, but maybe something like this?