# How to align a div inside td element using CSS class

Tags: html, center, alignment, html-table

It is working with this way

```
<td align="center">
```

But I want to use CSS class.

I defined class like this way but no luck

```
td
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    align: center;
}
```

Vertical align is working and text align is working for text. But it does not align div inside td with this way. I want to align div inside td.

Comment: Your script should work. There must be other css styles that override your style for td.

Comment: No you are not right. You are having a block element in your td which you need to style by itself.

Comment: Here a solution => https://stackoverflow.com/a/57590933/2736742

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```
div { margin: auto; }
```

This will center your div.

Div by itself is a blockelement. Therefor you need to define the style to the div how to behave.

Answer (score 8):

I cannot help you much without a small (possibly reduced) snippit of the problem. If the problem is what I think it is then it's because a **div** by default takes up **100% width**, and as such cannot be aligned.

What you may be after is to align the inline elements inside the div (such as text) with **text-align:center;** otherwise you may consider setting the div to **display:inline-block;**

If you do go down the inline-block route then you may have to consider my favorite IE hack.

```
width:100px;
display:inline-block;
zoom:1; //IE only
*display:inline; //IE only
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: divs has background images. so their sizes are changing. if they were taking 100% width i wouldn't ask it how to align :)